# Read File from Local Network like \\192.168.0.100\share\file.txt Android Code

Tags: java, android

please help me in android code for reading a file located in my shared network place..

\192.168.0.100\share\file.txt

```
try {               
    InputStream file = new FileInputStream("\\\\192.168.0.100\\share\\file.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         if(line.contains("text")) {
            line = line.substring(2, 5);
         }
         text.append(line);
         text.append('\n');
    }
    tv.setText(text);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    tv.setText(e.toString());
}
```

this is not working...
saying File / Directory not found.... 
I have checked and confirmed shared location.. it is working with other locally connected computers.

Please help me.

Comment: Can we use `FileInputStream` to access networked folders/files under Android? I think we need a library with Samba support or something...

Answer (score 0):

Using the `\\computer\resource` syntax as a file path is Windows-specific. That path doesn't work with "other locally connected computers", it works with *Windows* computers. Android, other Linux systems, and other Unix systems don't support that syntax.

You could use the [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) library to talk to your Windows shares.